# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'blogpost_post_id' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I'm stumped with the use of Pivot Table on Laravel. I've read several similar posts with no success.

I'm a complete beginner. Here's the message I have.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'blogpost_post_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `blogpost_blogtag` (`blogpost_post_id`, `blogtag_tag_id`) values (1, 2))

The issue is pretty simple. Laravel is adding the name of the table before the name of the column, and I can't find out why.

Laravel calls `blogpost_post_id` whereas the name of the column is simply `post_id`
Laravel calls `blogtag_tag_id` whereas the name of the column is simply `tag_id`

### The models

**Blogpost.php**

```
public function blogtags(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blogtag');
}
```

**Blogtag.php**

```
public function blogposts(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blogpost');
}

I've also declared in the **Postcategory.php** model the following

public function blogposts()
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Blogpost');
}
```

### The tables:

**blogpost table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blogposts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('post_id');
        $table->integer('post_editorid')->default(0);
        $table->string('post_title');
        $table->string('post_slug');
        $table->text('post_content');
        $table->integer('post_categoryid');
        $table->boolean('post_banned')->default(0);
        $table->integer('post_moderatorid')->default(0);
        $table->dateTime('post_bandate')->nullable($value = true);
        $table->string('post_picture')->nullable($value = true);
        $table->string('post_extlink')->nullable($value = true);
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Postcategories table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('postcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('cat_id');
        $table->string('cat_name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Blogtags table**

```
public function up()

{
    Schema::create('blogtags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('tag_id');
        $table->string('tag_kw')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**And the PIVOT table**

public function up()

```
{
    Schema::create('blogpost_blogtag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('tag_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And the controller (store)

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'posttitle' => 'required|min:4|max:255|string',
    'postcontent' => 'required|min:30|max:3000|string',
    'postpict' => 'nullable|image',
    'post_categoryid' => 'required',
    'postlink' => 'nullable|max:255|string',
    'blogtags' => 'nullable',

]);

    if ($request->hasFile('postpict')) {

        $postpict = $request->postpict;
        $postpict_new_name = time().$postpict->getClientOriginalName();
        $postpict->move('uploads/postpicts/', $postpict_new_name);
        $picturl = 'uploads/postpicts/' . $postpict_new_name;
    }else{
        $picturl = NULL;
    }

        $blogpost = Blogpost::create([
            'post_title' => $request->posttitle,
            'post_content' => $request->postcontent,
            'post_categoryid' => $request->post_categoryid,
            'post_picture' => $picturl,
            'post_extlink' => $request->postlink,
            'post_slug' => str_slug($request->posttitle)

        ]);

$blogpost->blogtags()->attach($request->blogtags);

$messageposttitle = $request->posttitle;
$message = $messageposttitle . ' is successfully stored';
$title = '';
Toastr::success($message, $title, ["positionClass" => "toast-top-center"]);

return redirect()->back();
```

}

**$blogpost->blogtags()->attach($request->blogtags);**

I'll be happy to learn about the mistake I've done.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying to execute when you get the error? Laravel *should* expect the column names `blogpost_id` and `blogtag_id` here. Not sure how you get an error for `blogpost_post_id` and `blogtag_tag_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use custom foreign-key

```
Blogpost.php

    public function blogtags(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blogtag','blogpost_blogtag','post_id','tag_id');
    }
```

---

```
Blogtag.php

public function blogposts(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blogpost','blogpost_blogtag','tag_id','post_id');
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly thank you. I'm going to read more on custom foreign-keys. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry to jump in on this answer but this may be of use to you. Laravel relationships docs. This explains the methods in more detail, including the defining of the columns like in this answer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Your comment is perfectly fine. It's actually the doc I was reading to deepen this topic, and you're right to say that it's very detailed :)

Comment: @Code-Me-A-Unicorn you are welcome. Can you mark this answer as right answer . It will help me to improve my profile. Tx

Comment: Done ! I didn't notice the button at first, thank you for your kind reminder